# Blazor page route parameters with strongly-typed domain model values

Tags: routes, blazor, domain-driven-design

I'm using strongly-typed domain model values for my domain object IDs rather than a primitive. For example: `readonly record struct AccountId(int Value)`. In the Blazor page route I am specifying something like `@page "/accounts/{accountId:int}"`, using a known route constraint. I would like to declare my Blazor component parameter like this:

`[Parameter] public AccountId AccountId { get; set; }`

instead of

`[Parameter] public int AccountId { get; set; }`

Can I use a custom type converter, value converter, model binder or other framework facility to achieve this?

I realize I can go with the flow and just use an int parameter and convert to the desired type in OnInitializaed or OnParametersSet but I have many pages and many types and would like this to be as simple and clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

URL routes will always be of primitive type, the only way to convert them to domain models is to handle them in OnParametersSet.

Using an In-memory State Container Service can be a good workaround.

I would use something like below:

```
public class AccountState
{
    private void NotifyStateChanged() => OnChange?.Invoke();
    public event Action? OnChange;
    public AccountId? SelectedAccountId {get; set;}
}
```

This state container can be set as a singleton service to the application and injected in pages where it is needed.

Now for navigation, you can route to '/accounts/details' and set the AccountState before navigating.

The Account Details page can then pick the AccountId from the injected State Container on initialization.
If you want, you can also persist the data of state container in local storage or session storage so that data stays there even when page is refreshed or browser is reopened.

(You need to call `_injectedAccountState.OnChange += StateHasChanged;` and also implement IDisposable Dispose method with `_injectedAccountState.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;`. For more details refer link to Microsoft documentation on state containers.)

[In-memory State Container Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly#in-memory-state-container-service-wasm)